# Scenebuilder not showing controller fields

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

There's a weird behaving I'm noticing in SceneBuilder, I successfully attach the scene to the wanted Controller as shown here :

[image]

but sometimes it can't detect the fields annotated with @FXML annotation

```
 public class MainViewController
    {
        EntityManager em;

        @FXML 
        public Parent View;
        @FXML 
        public BorderPane ContentArea;


        public MainViewController() 
        {
        }
...
```

[image]

Scenebuilder should give suggestions by showing the available @FXML annotated fields from the controller, sometimes it s working correctly , but sometimes it doesn't, until I close Eclipse reopen it, but don't understand the problem, and it s really handicapping me, is there any explanations ?

Comment: dont use reserved variables as variable name like 'View' use 'm_View' or something else.
to your problem: try clean and build, sometimes the gui caches the fxml and then it doesnt work.

Comment: I understand for the naming convention, but cleaning and building the project every time is not the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this problem from the other direction. When making changes in Scenebuilder and starting the Java application the changes are not in the GUI. I always have to make a clean first.

I think you are facing a similar problem, so try to clean your workspace. Maybe you have to restart Scenebuilder also.

Comment: Actually that's what I do, I clean, rebuild the project , restart scenebuilder,  but I started working with JavaFx and Java in general since like a Month , and this cleaning and rebuilding stuff already got me tired, hope I find a definitive solution for this issue